# Msql: on MYSQL Query Browser and MYSQL WorkBench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am currently learning mysql workbench, but I have gotten a book that uses mysql query browser. However, when I am trying to download query browser, it is stated that it is discontinued. So I am currently using workbench. However, I find it difficult to create procedure. What is workbench equivalence of procedure? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to a stored procedure, then those are listed in the schema navigator on the left panel. Expand the desired schema to see sections for Tables, Views, Stored Procedures, and Functions. Right-clicking on Stored Procedures displays an option to "Create Stored Procedure".

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you looking for?

[image]

If so, write-click on `Stored Procedures` and select `Create`.

Otherwise please clarify your problem.